# Fixed content in fullscreen and not fullscreen

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I fix a TextView on screen regardless of fullscreen and not fullscreen mode.
I want to make statusbar and ActionBar overlay my textview.

I want to toggle fullscreen by tapping, but keep the TextView on a fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

Hi May try this if you only want to disable the title bar

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Regards Joran

Comment: No, I want to toggle fullscreen by tapping on screen.

Comment: Can you add your code to the topic so i can find a soulution in this case @AVEbrahimi